# How to implement simple dynamodb table with daily value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'am learning AWS API Gateway + Lambda + Dynamodb by building a very simple API project.

I have a daily value starting from 2013-01-01 and keep updating every day, so basically is something like:

```
[
    {
        "value": 1776.09,
        "date": "2013-01-01"
    },
    {
        "value": 1779.25,
        "date": "2013-01-02"
    },
    // ...
    {
        "value": 2697.32,
        "date": "2018-11-22"
    }
]
```

In the API I want to get the data for a specific day and for a range (dateFrom - dateTo), and I've been reading about Dynamodb and planning to have `date` as partition key in format `YYYY-MM-DD` and no sorting key, but not sure if this is the correct aproach for this type of data and the range query I'm going to be doing as I assume I'm going to have to do a full table scan for the range query, although is a small data set.

Can someone point me if this aproach is right or do I need to reconsider my table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose will work.

However, if you want to improve the efficiency of the design, you could use a partition key of `YYYY` and then your sort key could be `MM-DD`. That way, you can use a query operation to limit the results (or you could still use a scan).

You could even use a single, constant value for the partition key and `date` as the sort key, but having the same partition key for every item is generally not recommended.

Either way, your data is small enough that you should probably just pick the implementation that is simplest to develop and maintain.

Comment: Thanks! your answer gives me great insight about partition and sort keys. But I have a question regarding the first aproach (`YYYY` as partition key and `MM-DD` as sort key: If I do it that way, would I have to restrict the range queries by year, or could I still make a query that overlaps multiple years, for example from 2013-01-01 to 2015-12-31? Or maybe have `YYYY` as partition key (even just the last two digits: 13, 14, 15, etc) and `YYYY-MM-DD` as sort key? So I can make an date query overlaping multiple years.

Comment: If your query spans multiple years, you can execute one query for each year and combine the results in your application, or you could do a table scan. Compared to a table scan, multiple queries will consume less RCU and (if you execute the queries in parallel) it will be faster.

Comment: If you’re going to use YYYY as the partition key, then you can’t get multiple years’ results even if you have a sort key of `yyyy-mm-dd`. Each `query` operation can only look at one partition key value.

Comment: Thank you for all that valuable info... just one last question: Is there going to be any performance difference if I use an integer type for the partition key over a string type, since it is going to be a number anyway?

Comment: I work on an application that has large tables, some with number keys and some with string keys. I have never had any noticeable performance difference caused by the key type.

Answer (score 0):

Copying my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54499379/3892213)

Few concepts of NOSQLdb

1. writes should be equally spread out on primary keys.
2. read should be equally spread out on primary keys.

The obvious thing that comes to mind looking at given problem and dyanamodb schema is

have key `logs` as primary key and `timestamp` as secondary key. And to do an aggregation use

`select * where pk=logs and sk is_between x and y`

but this will violate both the concepts. We are always writing on a single pk and always reading from the same.

Now to this particular problem,
Our PK should be random enough (so that no [hot keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html)) and deterministic enough (so that we can query)

we will have to make some assumptions about application while designing keys. let's say we decide that we will update every hour. hence can have 7-jan-2018-17 as a key. where 17 means 17th hour. this Key is deterministic but it is not random enough. and every update or read on 7th jan will mostly be going to same partition. To make the key random we can calculate hash of it using hashing algo like md5. let's say after taking hash, our key becomes 1sdc23sjdnsd. This will not make any sense if you are looking at table data. But if you want to know the event count on 7-jan-2018-17 you just hash the time and do a get from dynamodb with the hashkey.
if you want to know all the events on 7-jan-2018 you can do repeated 24 gets and aggregate the count.

Now this kind of schema will have issues where

1. If you decide to change from hourly to minute basis.
2. If most of your queries are run time like get me all the data for last 2,4,6 days. It will mean too many round trips to db. And it will be both time and cost inefficient.

Rule of thumb is **when query patterns are well defined, use NOSQL** and store the results for performance reasons. If you are trying to do a join or aggregation sort of queries on nosql, it is force fitting your use case based on your technology choice.

You can also looks at [aws recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html) of storing time series data.