# How to query records where datetime is greater than X in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB, and I need to get a list of records (in Java) which are from the last day. They all have a dateTime attribute.

Relevant attributes of the table I'm referring to:
customerUrl(string, hashkey), dateTime(number, range key), and a few other attributes which aren't relevant

I've already tried setting a Global Secondary Index with a hashkey of dateTime and no range key. This index is named 'performanceIndex'. I then tried to query it as follows:

```java
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withN(maximumAgeMillis));
DynamoDBQueryExpression<PingLog> pinglogQuery = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<PingLog>();
pinglogQuery.setKeyConditionExpression("dateTime > :val1");
pinglogQuery.setExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
pinglogQuery.setIndexName("performanceIndex");
pinglogQuery.setConsistentRead(false);
List<PingLog> pinglogs = PostDatabaseMapper.getInstance().query(PingLog.class, pinglogQuery);
```

However, the query permanently keeps going and never returns. I added a println statement before and after it, and only the first one actually printed.

Before this query I just did a scan with a filter, and that worked, but now we have so many records (80 million) that a scan takes forever. What should I do? Do I need a different secondary index? Is my query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a GSI with `yyyy-mm-dd` as the partition key, and `hh:mm:ss` as the sort key. (This might require backfilling the entire table, but if you query by date often, it will be worth it.) Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53439391/5563569) to a related question, which has some more details on this approach.

There is a potential complication depending on what sort of data access patterns you have. Is it fairly steady, or is it bursty? Will current items have a much higher write throughput than any other day?

If you’re dealing with time-series data, such as IoT sensor readings, this strategy may not work for you. You could have a hot partition in your GSI, which could put back-pressure in your main table and cause writes to be throttled. This is unlikely because of DynamoDB’s adaptive capacity, but it is possible.

In this case, you should consider DynamoDB’s recommended [best practice for handling time-series data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/design-patterns-for-high-volume-time-series-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/). It discusses how to deal with data that has different access requirements over time. The gist of their solution is to create separate tables for each period of time (day/month/year/whatever) so that data from different time frames can have different provisioned capacity.