# AWS DynamoDB table structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating a cryptocurrency bot and need to store its trade history in some place. Since AWS DynamoDB is free to use to a certain degree I think it can fulfill my needs but I have some problems regarding table structure.

Each trade has the following attributes:

- cryptocurrency symbol
- trade id provided by cryptocurrency exchange (it is unique only in combination with cryptocurrency symbol, i.e. symbol `A` can have trade id `1000` and symbol `B` also can have trade id `1000`)
- time when trade was executed (multiple trades can happen at the same time)
- price
- quantity

And each day I plan to make 1 select query for last 200 items sorted by `time` and also about 50 new item inserts.

From what I read a table needs to have a unique primary key so I used `cryptocurrency symbol` as a partition key and `trade id` as a sort key since both of them combined provide uniqueness but if I'm not mistaken this setup does not allow me to sort data by `time`.

One solution that I can think of is generating new and completely unique `trade ids` by myself and do not rely on `trade ids` provided by exchange and then use `time` as a sort key, but I would like to avoid it.

Is there maybe a better way to do this?

Comment: Your solution will not work for what you want to do because the sort key only sorts within a partition, not across partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use symbol and tradeId as the primary key, and in order to query by date, you can create a GSI with `yyyy-mm-dd` as the partition key, and `hh:mm:ss` (or the full timestamp if you prefer) as the sort key. Since you’re doing 50 inserts per day, you could even use `yyyy-mm` as the GSI partition key.

In order to select the latest 200, you query the GSI with a key condition expression of `yyyymmdd = :today`, sort = descending, limit 200. If you get less than 200 results, repeat the query for the previous day. If you still have less than 200 results, continue querying one day at a time until you have the number you want. (If you choose to use `yyyy-mm` as the GSI partition key, adapt this strategy to use months instead of days.)

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53439391/5563569) to a related question, which has some more details on this approach.

This approach *might* not scale very well, but since you are trying to stay within the free tier of DynamoDB, you probably don’t need to worry about scalability.

Now, if you don’t care about best practices at all, just use `yyyy-mm-dd` as the partition key of the main table, and then use `hh:mm:ss:symbol:tradeId` as the sort key. You will be able to query the main table by date (but not by anything else).

Comment: I've read a little about GSI and what do you think about creating a new attribute which would have constant value across all items and would serve as the partition key of the GSI since it doesn't have to be unique and then use timestamp as the sort key. It would probably be terrible performance wise but I don't care about performance, just need an easy way to store and retrieve some data.

Comment: That would probably be okay for you if you don’t expect to have too much data (less than 10 GB). To all other readers: this is a DynamoDB anti-pattern, which will not work at scale.